# Select Subset of Range in VBA based on value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select a subset of data in a range and copy it to another sheet in Excel. My thought process was as follows

1. Find the first and last instance of the value in a column
2. Copy from the first instance down to the last instance and all the way to the Right
3. Paste the range of data into my sheet

I am having trouble finding the first and last instance of the value in a column and setting the range to copy.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Button()
  'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ws_temp, ws_data As Worksheet
  Dim data_rng As Range

  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  Set ws_temp = wb.Sheets("Template")
  Set ws_data = wb.Sheets("data")
  'declare id
  Dim id As Integer
  Set id= ws_temp.Range("B4").Value 'this is where the value is stored 

  'find first instance of id in data.
  ' The data starts in cell A6 and extends to column O. The number of rows will be variable
  'find last instance of pitcher id

  'Set data_rng
  Set data_rng = wb.ws_data.Range("first instance":O&"second instance")

  'Copy data_rng
  data_rng.Copy wb.ws_temp.Range("A8") 'the data will always go in cell A8 on the Template sheet

  'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you consider using [`Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find), specifying the `After` parameter?

Comment: `Set id=` will give you an error. Only Object variables need to be Set. Value variables like Integers dont need to be Set. Remove Set, just do `id=`.

Comment: After you have the first and second instance (from Range.Find like BigBen suggested), you can define your finished range like `With wb.ws_data: Set data_rng = .Range(FirstInstance, .Cells(SecondInstance.Row,.Columns.Count)): End With` which will get you the range you described in your post.

Comment: No I have not used Find before. Are these full answers? I would like to give credit where credit is due.

Comment: @JackArmstrong Is the data in the column sorted so that all the instances you are interested in are in a contiguous range?

Comment: The cells are in a contiguous range such that the values between the first instance and the last instance will be the same.

Comment: If your version of Excel includes `XMATCH`, use that to search top down for first match, and bottom up for mast match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is use `Application.Match` to find the row of the first instance then use `Application.CountIf` to count the no of occurrences of the search term.

With that information you should be able to get the subset of the data you want to copy using `Resize`.

```vb
Sub Button()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws_temp, ws_data As Worksheet
Dim data_rng As Range
Dim id As Long
Dim lngFirstRow As Long
Dim lngNoRows As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws_temp = wb.Sheets("Template")
    Set ws_data = wb.Sheets("data")
    
    ' get search id
    id = ws_temp.Range("B4").Value

    ' find row of first occurence of id
    lngFirstRow = Application.Match(id, ws_data.Columns(2), 0)
    
    ' find count of id
    lngNoRows = Application.CountIf(ws_data.Columns(2), id)
    
    Set data_rng = ws_data.Range("B" & lngFirstRow).Resize(lngNoRows, 14)
      
    'Copy data_rng
    data_rng.Copy ws_temp.Range("A8")    'the data will always go in cell A8 on the Template sheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: There is a type mismatch error when finding row of first occurence of id. I think this is cause it returns a double not a long

Comment: Is the value you are looking for definitely in column A on the sheet 'data'? Is the value from B4 on 'Template' the same data type as the values in column A on 'data'?

Comment: The value I am looking for is on 'data' in column B. I need to return columns B-O or A-O. I can live without returning column A. I am receiving an error when setting lngFirstRow as Error 2042. I have declared them as Variant's, but still receive mismatch error.

Comment: I'll update the code to look in column B rather than column A.

Comment: I see what is happening. So it does select the data from column B, but it does not copy and paste it.

Comment: @JackArmstrong - There was an error in the original code that I should have fixed - I've done so now.